# Is it possible to mock a Scala implicit class?

Tags: scala, mockito, implicit

I can extend my Scala class `Foo` with additional methods via an implicit class:

```
trait Foo {
  def bar: String
}

object FooExtensions {
  object implicits {
    implicit class FooOps(foo: Foo) {
      def baz: String = "baz"
    }
  }
}
```

But can I mock out those methods?

```
import org.mockito.Mockito
import org.scalatest.WordSpec
import org.scalatest.mockito.MockitoSugar

class MySpec extends WordSpec with MockitoSugar {
  "My mock" should {
    "handle methods from implicit classes" in {
      import FooExtensions.implicits._
      val foo = mock[Foo]
      Mockito.when(foo.baz).thenReturn("bix") // fails at runtime
    }
  }
}
```

This compiles, but fails with

```
when() requires an argument which has to be 'a method call on a mock'.
For example:
    when(mock.getArticles()).thenReturn(articles);

Also, this error might show up because:
1. you stub either of: final/private/equals()/hashCode() methods.
   Those methods *cannot* be stubbed/verified.
   Mocking methods declared on non-public parent classes is not supported.
2. inside when() you don't call method on mock but on some other object.

org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.MissingMethodInvocationException: 
when() requires an argument which has to be 'a method call on a mock'.
For example:
    when(mock.getArticles()).thenReturn(articles);

Also, this error might show up because:
1. you stub either of: final/private/equals()/hashCode() methods.
   Those methods *cannot* be stubbed/verified.
   Mocking methods declared on non-public parent classes is not supported.
2. inside when() you don't call method on mock but on some other object.
```

Is it possible to mock methods added via implicit classes? Hopefully with Mockito (or [mockito-scala](https://github.com/mockito/mockito-scala)) but I'm interested in any approach that works.

Comment: Not sure if you can or can't mock an extension method added trough an implicit class. But, IMHO you shouldn't. Usually an extension method is just nice syntax for other method, you can mock that method and everything will work. Or you can create another implicit class in a closer scope which can be the mock, but then you are not testing the implicit class, not either what the implicit class uses.

Answer (score 5):

Thing about extension methods, is that they are basically a syntactic sugar:

```
trait Foo
implicit class ExtensionMethods(foo: Foo) {
  def bar: String = "bar
}

foo.bar
```

is equal to

```
new ExtensionMethods(foo).bar
```

So mocking:

```
Mockito.when(foo.bar).thenReturn("bix")
```

becomes:

```
Mockito.when(new ExtensionMethods(foo).bar).thenReturn("bix")
```

I think there is no workaround - perhaps PowerMock could let you change class constructor..., but with normal Mockito it is impossible.

Usually, it is not a problem though. That is because either:

- you put into extension methods behavior, that only depends on extended value and passed parameters (and extended method is quite often pure function that doesn't require mocking) - if you want to change something there, you change input,
- if behavior should change, you implement it inside a type class, and make extension method use that type class to inject behavior

  ```
  trait Bar {
    def bar: String
  }
  object Bar {
    implicit val defaultBar: Bar = new Bar { def bar = "bar" }
  }

  implicit class ExtensionMethods(foo: Foo) {
    def bar(implicit bar: Bar): String = bar.bar
  }

  // in test
  implicit var overridenBar: Bar = ...
  assert(foo.bar === "sth")
  ```

On a side note: the more functional you'll get the less you'll need to mock things as everything will depend only on input passed inside, and a cascade of mocks will become just a code smell - too tight coupling, too large interfaces, etc. Problem is that many Java libraries do not even follow SOLID principles, which makes them both hard to use/test with FP as well as bad OOP on its own. I'm telling this in case you feel mocking is the only way to go in your case.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to achieve that is to use implicit conversions rather than implicit classes

**This is a hack intended to show how this could be achieved, but I'd urge to take a look at the code and see why you actually need to do this**

So, following your example, you could modify the code to look like this

```
trait Foo {
  def bar: String
}

object FooExtensions {
  object implicits {
    implicit fooToOps(foo: Foo): FooOps = new FooOps(foo)
    class FooOps(foo: Foo) {
      def baz: String = "baz"
    }
  }
}
```

and your test

```
import org.scalatest.WordSpec
import org.mockito.MockitoSugar

  class MySpec extends WordSpec with MockitoSugar {
    "My mock" should {
      "handle methods from implicit classes" in {
        val fooOps = mock[FooOps]
        implicit fooToOps(foo: Foo): FooOps = fooOps
        val foo = mock[Foo]
        when(foo.baz) thenReturn "bix" // works
      }
    }
  }
```

the other thing to consider is that in your production you need to get an implicit parameter of the shape `Foo => FooOps` so when you call that method from the test the actual implicit mock is provided...

As I said, you can make it work like this, but I agree with Mateusz that you shouldn't need to